# Hibernate and JPA @PreUpdate and @PrePersist not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run some code just before Updating or Saving. I have in my entity:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Table(name="file_management", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
@Entity
public class FileManagement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SEARCH_STRING", length = 1000)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String searchString;

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    void updateSearchString() {

        final String fullSearchString = StringUtils.join(Arrays.asList(
                name),
                " ");

        this.searchString = StringUtils.substring(fullSearchString, 0, 999);

    }
}
```

I have in my FileManagementRepository:

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE FileManagement SET name = :name WHERE id = :id")
    public void updateFile(long id, String name);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO file_management (name, filename, created_by, create_date, is_active, is_deleted) VALUES (:name, :filename, :createdBy, :createdDate, :isActive, :isDeleted)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void createFileWithFilename(String name, String filename, String createdBy, Date createdDate, boolean isActive, boolean isDeleted);
```

and in my FileManagementService.java

```
public void updateFileWithFilename(String id, String name) {
        fileManagementRepository.updateFile(Long.parseLong(id), name);
    }
public boolean createFileWithFilename(String name, String filename, String createdBy, Date createdDate, boolean isActive, boolean isDeleted) {
        fileManagementRepository.createFileWithFilename(name, filename, createdBy, createdDate, isActive, isDeleted);
        return true;
    }
```

But the problem is the updateSearchString() method is not called when I update or insert a new row. The search_string column is (null)

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You are using queries to do the updates not using the entities. Why? Basically you are using JPA for persistence and then workaround it with creating your own queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that entities that are inserted or updated using native SQL or JPQL in this way will by pass the persistent context and persistence context will not manage them. However , `@PreUpdate` and `@PrePersist` only work for the entities that are managed by persistence context , so your `@PreUpdate` and `@PrePersist` will not execute for them.

I think you should insert and update the entities in a more JPA way which ensure persistence context will manage them:

```
@Service
public class FileManagementService{

    @Autowired
    private FileManagementRepository fileManagementRepository;

    @Transactional 
    public void updateFileWithFilename(String id, String name) {
       Optional<FileManagement> file= fileManagementRepository.findById(id);
       if(file.isPresent()){
           file.get().setName(name);
       }else{
          throw new RuntimeException("Record does not exist");
       }
    }

    @Transactional 
    public void createFileWithFilename(String name, String filename, String createdBy, Date createdDate, boolean isActive, boolean isDeleted) {
       FileManagement file= new FileManagement(name,fileName,........);
       fileManagementRepository.save(file);
    }
}
```